# perl: sort arrayref inside a hashref

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

I have the following structure:

```
my $hsh = {
  arr => [
    1,
    3,
    6,
    4,
    2
  ]
}
```

I want to sort `$hsh->{arr}`, but I can't figure out how.  `sort $h->{arr}` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$hsh->{arr} = [sort @{$hsh->{arr}}];
```

Comment: That needlessly creates a new array, which needlessly avoids `sort`'s in-place optimization.

Answer (score 3):

```
sort @{ $hsh->{arr} }
```

See http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+Quick+Reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
sort @{ $hsh->{arr} }
```

References about references:

- [Mini-Tutorial: Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408)
- [References quick reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927)
- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)

---

If you want to sort in-place<sup>[1]</sup>, use:

```
@{ $hsh->{arr} } = sort @{ $hsh->{arr} };
```

If you want to create a new array:

```
my @a = sort @{ $hsh->{arr} };
```

If you want to create a new anonymous array:

```
my $a = [ sort @{ $hsh->{arr} } ];
```

---

1. This doesn't just effectively sort in place, but actually does sort in-place. because `sort` is optimized to sort in-place when you have something of form `ARRAY = sort ARRAY` (or with a compare block of function).